# How to debug flask.app with pycharm 2.x that's running on gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I'm developing a flask.app that uses web socket functionality and installed [flask-socket](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sockets) to provide that. So the flask-socket developer recommends [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) as web server. My question is now how to connect the remove debugger of pycharm with gunicorn to intercept the execution with breakpoints.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`Settings > Project Settings > Python Debugger`

There's an option in there to enable "gevent compatible debugging".

Then, go into your debugger settings (shortcut is through the toolbar, click the dropdown near the play/debug icons and select "Edit Configurations"

Set the "Script" to your virtualenv's isntallation of gunicorn, something like:

`/Users/iandouglas/.virtualenvs/defaultenv/bin/gunicorn`

Set the "Script Parameters" to something like
`-b 192.168.1.1:9000 app:yourappname` (assuming your primary starting script is called app.py and you're refering to it as 'yourappname'

the "Working directory" will be automatically set otherwise set it to wherever your code lives: `/Users/iandouglas/PycharmProjects/MyExampleApp`

I have a separate config file for my gunicorn settings, which specifies a host/port but I still had to specify the `-b 0.0.0.0:5001` parameter to force gunicorn to bind to all IPs on my machine on port 5001.

p.s.

One important step is to add this envvar as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63692514/248616)

```
PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO
```

Comment: In PyCharm 2.7.3 under `Settings > Project Settings > Python Debugger` are only two options: "Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging" and "Collect run-time types information for code insight". Did you installed additional plugins?

Comment: No, I've always had "gevent compatible debugging" in my editor, both v2 and v3. I do use the Professional edition... perhaps they don't include it in the free Community Edition.

Comment: Version 3.4 of the CE has `Gevent compatible debugging` next to the other two options @arbyter mentioned.

Comment: Thanks alot for that! How simple was that!

Comment: this is an old post, but helpful for some people still. If while debugging, the process suddenly restarts, it's because of gunicorn worker timeout. You can set it higher for longer debugging time, use `--timeout INT` to your script parameters.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working in recent versions. Execution is not stopped at the breakpoints in my case

Comment: I was able to load my gunicorn config file. Instead of the param `-b 192.168.1.1:9000`, I just gave the param `-c <path/to/gunicorn/config/file>`

Comment: for future reader: if you wish to set envs in bulk: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708476/1781024

Comment: I have same issue with @Eldamir ie cannot get the breakpoints working ie can Run but cannot Debug (it gets hang)

Comment: how would this work for a project in a docker on your local machine (mac if it makes a difference)

Answer (score 12):

My case for PyCharm 2018.1.3 Professional:

1. Go to run/debug configurations
   [creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)
2. Choose new "Python" config
3. Script path: your_path_to_/venv/bin/gunicorn
4. Parameters(for my case): `-b :5001 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - "run:create_application()"`
5. Python interpreter: your venv python version for project
6. Working directory: path to your project
7. Save and press DEBUG (Shift+F9)
8. be happy!

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to debug on Pycharm 2020.2.1 and the break points weren't correctly working even though the Gevent compatible debugging was enabled. It turned out that I had to disable Cython for my run configuration via setting the environment variable as described [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42679) to make it work.

```
PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO
```

Comment: You are my savior @Philipp!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution works for me, but I was facing myproject module not found error, which was solved by using:

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application`

Pycharm ✅

instead of

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 'myproject.wsgi:application'`

Pycharm ❌

Answer (score -3):

> - edit your flask launch python file

```
$ vim manage.py
```

> - remove debug option setting

```
from web import app
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=app.config["PORT"], debug=app.config["DEBUG"])
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9998, debug=False)
```