# How to set environment variables in PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I have started to work on a Django project, and I would like to set some environment variables without setting them manually or having a bash file to source.

I want to set the following variables:

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://127.0.0.1:5432/my_db_name
export DEBUG=1
# there are other variables, but they contain personal information
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538859/pycharm-set-environment-variable-for-run-manage-py-task), but that does not solve what I want. In addition, I have tried setting the environment variables in **Preferences**-> **Build, Execution, Deployment**->**Console**->**Python Console**/**Django Console**, but it sets the variables for the interpreter.

Comment: Setting variables in pycharm has one disadvantage, that is you lose them if you delete the profile. An alternative is just to set a default value like the following import os os.getenv(key='DATABASE_URL', default='postgres://127.0.0.1:5432/my_db_name')

Comment: I think if you use the approach mentioned in my answer you won't lose the environment variables since they will be in the file you use. This answer is not addressing the question since it refers how to set them in PyCharm not if they are lose or not.

Comment: I also do not consider a good idea to hardcode values directly in code. This is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

**You can set environmental variables in Pycharm's run configurations menu.**

1. Open the Run Configuration selector in the top-right and click `Edit Configurations...`

[image: Edit Configurations...]

2. Select the *correct* file from the menu, find `Environmental variables` and click `...`

[image: Environment variables]

3. Add or change variables, then click `OK`

[image: Editing environmental variables]

You can [access your environmental variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4906977/3357935) with [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ)

```
import os
print(os.environ['SOME_VAR'])
```

Comment: oh, I was just trying to type on that line, the triple dot looked grayed out so i didn't even think to click on it.

Comment: I tried this method but PyCharm doesn't pick the defined env var (I specifically tried to set DATABASE_URL). Looks like a PyCharm bug.

Comment: @LNI in PyCharm there are two places where we can set env variables. One is for running environment(and it sets how Joran showed) and also we can set variables which will be available for console in Pycharm(and it sets here Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console )

Comment: Yeh this seems like the right answer to me. I would add that if you set the environmental variable in the Defaults/Python config, then it will be used every time you right-click on a script and run it

Comment: This worked for me. Had to restart my interpreter first though.

Comment: why doesn't work this in my PyCharm 2021.2.1 (Professional Edition), using on Ubuntu 18.04.6 bionic. This clearly  'simle things' not working that's so frustrating. Printing out sorted(os.environ.items()) from inside django.conf.__init__ doesn't even lists PYTHONUNBUFFERED - very frustrating.

Comment: **If it doesn't work** make sure you've set the variables for the correct category in step 2. (i accidentally didn't set it on "Python" but on "Flask")

Answer (score 174):

I was able to figure out this using a PyCharm plugin called [EnvFile](https://github.com/Ashald/EnvFile). This plugin, basically allows setting environment variables to run configurations from one or multiple files.

The installation is pretty simple:

**Preferences** > **Plugins** > **Browse repositories...** > *Search for "Env File"* > **Install Plugin**.

Then, I created a file, in my project root, called `environment.env` which contains:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://127.0.0.1:5432/my_db_name
DEBUG=1
```

Then I went to **Run**->**Edit Configurations**, and I followed the steps in the next image:

[image: Set Environment Variables]

In 3, I chose the file `environment.env`, and then I could just click the play button in PyCharm, and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf I can't thank you enough for this answer. It looks like Pycharm can't pick up env vars sources in .bashrc (I'm on Linux). This plugin saved me a lot of time as I can use postactivate file as source.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf yes, sorry. I mean 2017.2.4

Comment: Working here on 2017.3. Thanks!

Comment: Working in 2017.2

Comment: too bad it does not see .env file, i had to rename it to dev.env

Comment: @krinker, are you on Mac OS?

Comment: Yes. I added this to the Finder so now I can see .env there, but even after restarting PyCharm, I still don't see it when I browse through PyCharm
``` defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES. ```

Comment: @krinker, when you are browsing for the file, please press, `cmd` + `shift`+`.` to show the hidden files.

Comment: Anyone got this to work with the Python Console and Terminal too? It seems quite useless to me to only be able to set it for the runtime environment, but none of the other subfunctionalities.

Comment: Please keep in mind .env variables can not be defined with export.
For example `REDIS_HOST=localhost`, but if you will define with `export REDIS_HOST=localhost` then it will not work.

Comment: This is broken in the most recent version of Professional Edition.

Answer (score 36):

The original question is:

> How to set environment variables in PyCharm?

The two most-upvoted answers tell you how to set environment variables for PyCharm **Run/Debug Configurations** - manually enter them in "Environment variables" or use EnvFile plugin.

After using PyCharm for many years now, I've learned there are other key areas you can set PyCharm environment variables. EnvFile won't work for these other areas!

Here's where ELSE to look (in Settings):

- Tools > Terminal > Environment variables
- Languages & Frameworks > Django > Environment variables
- Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console > Environment variables
- Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Django Console > Environment variables

and of course, your run/debug configurations that was already mentioned.

Comment: This answer is the best here IMO. The only thing I'm missing is how to set it so that it also applies to `django_test_manage.py`.

Comment: Thank you - variables from python run config don't translate to the console, or the terminal either. So this is very important to understand, you essentially have to set them in multiple places.

Answer (score 20):

This functionality has been added to the IDE now (working Pycharm 2018.3)

Just click the `EnvFile` tab in the run configuration, click `Enable EnvFile` and click the + icon to add an env file

[image: Example with the glorious material theme]

Update: Essentially the same as the answer by @imguelvargasf but the the plugin was enabled by default for me.

Comment: I am pycharm 2019, and I don't see the tab `EnvFile`. Is this available in Python configuration (your screenshot is DjangoServer)?

Comment: he has the "EnvFile" plugin installed.

Comment: this solution did not work for pycharm 2021

Comment: did not work for PyCharm 2022.2.2 (Professional Edition)

Comment: Worked in 2022.3.2 (Requires the EnvFile plugin)

Answer (score 7):

This is what you can do to source an .env (and .flaskenv) file in the **pycharm flask/django console**. It would also work for a normal python console of course.

1. Do `pip install python-dotenv` in your environment (the same as being pointed to by pycharm).
2. Go to: **Settings > Build ,Execution, Deployment > Console > Flask/django Console**
3. In **"starting script"** include something like this near the top:

   `from dotenv import load_dotenv`
   `load_dotenv(verbose=True)`

The .env file can look like this:
`export KEY=VALUE`

It doesn't matter if one includes `export` or not for dotenv to read it.

As an alternative you could also source the .env file in the activate shell script for the respective virtual environement.

Comment: thank you, this answer actually addresses the env being in the terminal and not just in the run config.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the environment variables are in a file and store like below.
Copy all of them to clipboard `Ctrl+A` -> `Ctrl+C`

[image: Environment Variables]

Then click on `Edit Configurations` -> `Environment Variables`.
[image: PyCharm Env settings]

Now click on the small paste icon, and all the environment variables, will be available for usage in current environment.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

None of the above methods worked for me. If you are on Windows, try this on PyCharm terminal:

```
setx YOUR_VAR "VALUE"
```

You can access it in your scripts using `os.environ['YOUR_VAR']`.

Answer (score 1):

This method helped me a lot for calling environmental variable from a .env file and its really easy to implement too.

1. Create a .env file in the root folder of the project
2. Install a package called "**python-dotenv**"
3. Import and load the package in the **.py file** where you want to use the environment variable as follows

   ```
    import os
    from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

    load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
    any_secret_var = os.get_env("SECRET_KEY")
   ```

and BOOM it will work like magic

And the **.env file** should look like,
don't place any qoutes around the values in the .env file

```
    SECRET_KEY=any_secret_value_you_need_to_place_in
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone want to set environment variables for **all** their Run/Debug Configuration, I list my solution here.

1. Go to the Edit Configurations as pointed by other answers.
2. Click **edit the configuration templates** in the panel.
3. Edit environment variables there.

By doing so, the variables will be there every time you create a new configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Solution tested with virtual environment.

Create an script that define and export or source the env vars. Then define the script as the python interpreter of an existing virtual env. The solution works for any task like run, debug, console ...

Example script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash


DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
export VAR1="TEST1"
source $DIR/../../.env
$DIR/python "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to set environment variable in pycharm terminal. Just add the following lines at the end of `venv/bin/activate` script if you are using a virtual environment:

```
export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)
```

Answer (score -2):

In the Pycharm Python console just type

```
ENV_VAR_NAME="STRING VARIABLE"
INT_VAR_NAME=5
```

Unlike other Python text editors, you do not add `export` in Pycharm

Comment: That's not working!