# How to convert these lines in .bash_profile in PyCharm Environment variables

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow, environment-variables, pycharm

I have several lines in .bash_profile in my macOS needed for the tensorflow.

```
export PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export CUDA_HOME=~/cudnn
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CUDA_HOME/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

When I run my python program in Terminal, everything is fine, since it loads the .bash_profile first.

However, PyCharm don't source .bash_profile. So, we need to provide Environment variables in PyCharm.

Can someone please help me to update those lines in PyCharm. I have hard time to make it correct.

[image]

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm

Comment: @yklsga step wise, I know how to do it, but I dont think my translate from .bash_profile into the PyCharm is correct, since I still see missing lib when I run the program in PyCharm.

Comment: before running try to print all environment variables that are available to you, `import os
for k,v in os.environ.items():
    print(k+" "+v)` , see whether lib is available to you or not