# Load Environment Variables from shell script before python task | Pycharm 2018.1 PRO

Tags: python, shell, pycharm, environment-variables, celery

I'm trying to run a python task within run/debug configuration task option.

My problem is that I need to load some environment variables from a bash script.

In my normal terminal is as simple as `<source file.sh>` and then I can execute my script without any problem.

I already tried doing a external tool (to execute the sh file) an put on "before launch" option inside run/debug configuration

but did not work.

Any ideas/help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set environment variables in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the environment variables before starting PyCharm.  This way, they should propagate to processes launched by PyCharm, and you c an re-use the existing bash script.

But if you can put the environment variable settings into a file of the appropriate format, the [`EnvFile` suggestion in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708476/8316315) appears to be a good solution.