# pycharm: run python program after executing bash script

Tags: bash, pycharm, environment-variables

My python program expects a few environment variables to be populated first (API KEYs etc.)

I have a bash script that fetches the temporary API keys, and sets it using `EXPORT`, and i'm able to call the script successfully.

If i use pycharm's `run` option, the environment variables are understandably missing.

Other than setting the Env variables manually in the pycharm [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm) , can i ask it to run the bash script and then execute my python file in the same bash context ?

I have a script `populate_env` available in my `PATH`.