# Set the same environment variables for all configurations in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables, celery

I have a project with Celery and a lot of different workers.
How to avoid copy-pasting environment variables in PyCharm each time to each configuration for Run/Debug?
Is there any way to set them in projects settings?

Comment: This question might be answered by looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm

Comment: Thanks, haven't mentioned the Accepted answer, because there is another with more votes and large screenshots, that hides the actually useful thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708476/3722635), it is about installing plugin [EnvFile](https://github.com/Ashald/EnvFile) and put all environment variables to a file.

> The installation is pretty simple:
>
> **Preferences** > **Plugins** > **Browse repositories**... > Search for "Env File" > **Install Plugin**.
>
> Then, create a file, called **environment.env** which contains:
>
> ```
> DATABASE_URL=postgres://127.0.0.1:5432/my_db_name
> DEBUG=1 Then I went
> ```
>
> to **Run** -> **Edit Configurations**, and I followed the steps in the next image:

[image]

P.S. in the question by link there are 2 answers with many votes (for now: 44 and 42). And accepted works here, but other with more votes and large screenshots - don't, because it is how to set environment variables in general.