# How can I set env variable in PyCharm one time for all tests (use one run configuration for all tests)?

Tags: python, pycharm

How can I specify environment variable in PyCharm for all runs.
Can I do it without extension from this answer [Set the same environment variables for all configurations in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777957/set-the-same-environment-variables-for-all-configurations-in-pycharm)

I know that I can set environment variables for one test when I want to run anoter test with environmet variable I have to set env variable again)

```
Open the Run Configuration  --> Edit Configurations --> Environment Variables --> Set variable
```

[image]

How can I set environment variable in PyCharm one time for all tests (use one run configuration for all tests)?

Comment: Relatedly, I can click on the "arrow" in the left hand gutter to start one unit test, but how do I make sure the right environment variables are set for that one test?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this, but this seems to work for me.

I set up a child class of [`unittest.TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).

```
class GRTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Setting up a generic way for us to store env vars before running unit tests
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GRTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        os.environ['TESTVAR'] = 'TEST value'
```

Then, use this child class `GRTestCase` in your tests, rather than unittest.TestCase. You can test this by running the method `test_env_var` in the next class (right click on the green arrow in the left gutter):

```
class tests(GRTestCase):
    
    def test_env_var(self):
        tmpvar = os.getenv('TESTVAR')
        print(tmpvar)
        self.assertEqual(tmpvar, 'TEST value')
```

You should see that your test passes and *TEST value* gets printed to the console. One advantage here could be that this should work even if you're not in PyCharm.