# Using Heroku config vars in PyCharm

Tags: python, heroku, pycharm

I am creating a Python app and hosting it on Heroku. Recently I have been playing around with Heroku's Config Vars so that I can keep my secret keys away from prying eyes. So I put my secret key in the Heroku config vars:

[image: Heroku Config Vars]

And then in my Python code, I access the secret var using something like this:

```
print("This is my secret key: " + str(os.environ.get("secret_key")))
```

And when hosted on Heroku, that works great!

```
>>>This is my secret key: 1234
```

But I would also like to be able to run this code local in PyCharm. Typically I would just do something like:

```
secret_key = sys.argv[1]
```

And set the secret key in the script parameters of PyCharm. But that will not run on Heroku. Is there something that I can put in the script parameters to make this work? Something like this? (tried, does not work...)

[image: Pycharm Script Parameters]

Or is there some other way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you use different code in production (respecting environment variables) vs. locally (requiring settings to be passed in as CLI arguments)? Just use environment variables everywhere. You can [set them in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708480/354577), or you could create an untracked, ignored `.env` file containing your environment variables:

```
secret_key=1234
```

And run your code using a tool that populates environment variables from such a file, e.g. [`heroku local`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#run-your-app-locally-using-the-heroku-local-command-line-tool-start-your-app-locally) or [`pipenv run`](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/advanced/#automatic-loading-of-env). The `.env` flow is [officially endorsed by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#copy-heroku-config-vars-to-your-local-env-file).