# Best Practices Python - Where to store API KEYS/TOKENS

Tags: python, api-key, bearer-token

I am building a system that uses API tokens and keys to access services, but where is the best place to store them? I want to push the code to GitHub without pushing the tokens.

Currently, I've placed them in a blank file named `Constants.py` and, in the main python file, I import `Constants.py`.

`API_KEY_SERVICE = "ABC123ABC"`

Main.py:

```
import Constants
service_key = Constants.API_KEY_SENDGRID
```

Comment: One option is read these constants from environment variables. That way you won't have any secrets in your source code.

Comment: As a first shot you should add the file to `.gitignore` to prevent accidental commits and pushes.

Comment: Another is using a yaml file and adding the .yaml to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you are attempting is the correct way to segregate sensitive information from code. You should include the `constants.py` in your `.gitignore` file which will prevent git from tracking that file and thus not pushing it to github.

For .gitignore, refer: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 13):

There are a few options:

1. Store it locally as you have and, as Sebastin Santy noted, add constants.py to your .gitignore file.
2. Store it as an environment variable if you're using a conda virtual environment. Virtual environments aren't stored; the requirements for creating one are in the requirements.txt file. You can find more on the steps from the [conda documetation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#macos-and-linux)
3. Use the [OS module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#file-names-command-line-arguments-and-environment-variables)
4. If you have more than one set of environment variables, you might consider using [decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/)
5. If you're using AWS, you'll want to store the (what would be third party) keys in their own area with its own IAM. There are two ways recommended by AWS.

- a. [IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html)
- b. [Store Secrets using Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/the-right-way-to-store-secrets-using-parameter-store/)
- c. [Store Secrets using Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/index.html)  - **Current method recommended by AWS**

Comment: I like that you included AWS in your answer but im curious why you didnt mention AWS Secrets Manager?

Comment: @BilliD - No, you're right. That was an oversight. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

There are some good answers here. To add to them, I think we can also use the keyring module, which will read the credentials from Windows credentials or Mac OS keychain.
But I would love to hear the thoughts of the community. Thanks.

here's the link to that - https://pypi.org/project/keyring/

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to add more to the **environment variables** approach, which is not limited to `conda` virtual environment. One can use a `.env` file, and place it in the root directory of your project. Meanwhile, you should include `.env` in the `.gitignore` file.

What makes this approach different compared to using `constants.py`, especially for those who do not subscribe a **Key Management Service**?

- [Best practices for api key safety, BY OPENAI](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/5112595-best-practices-for-api-key-safety). As they suggested, **use environment variables in place of your API key**.
- There are a lot of tutorials, such as [How to set environment variables in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm).
- The `.env` file is supported by PyCharm, as in `Edit Configurations`.
- Third-party plugin support, such as [EnvFile](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile).
- Python module available, [dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv).