# os.getenv('CORENLP_HOME') returning None and os.environ['CORENLP_HOME'] returning KeyError but echo $CORENLP_HOME returns a path in terminal

Tags: python, environment-variables, stanford-nlp

I am aware a lot of similar questions exist but I am unable to understand what is happening here. I am trying to follow instructions for this Stanford CoreNLP python wrapper [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/corenlp_client.html#setup), one of the steps is to set the`CORENLP_HOME` environment variable.

I ran the command:

`export CORENLP_HOME=/path/to/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05`

Restarted the terminal, or actually added to my `~/.bash_profile`. Now when I do a `echo $CORENLP_HOME` in the terminal I am able to see the path correctly. But on the other hand, if the corenlp wrapper code tries to find the same path through python code it returns `None`.

So I separately checked two python commands, the wrapper code uses `os.getenv()`:

```
import os 

print(os.getenv('CORENLP_HOME')) #prints None
print(os.environ['CORENLP_HOME']) #Throws a KeyError exception
```

MacOS version: 10.15.4;Python: 3.7.6

I don't have a very deep understanding of environment variables in general, I want to understand what is happening here, or if I am missing something simple. Happy to provide more information!

Comment: The first print works for me. You don't need to use $ on os.environ, just the environment name.

Comment: You are running all tests in the same shell ? Every session have you own env.

Comment: Please, let me know if the first works in the same bash session. I'll write a complete response after that.

Comment: The $ on os.environ was a typo when I typed this question. I am running the python code in PyCharm, and the terminal command through the PyCharm terminal. My system terminal shell is zsh.

Comment: Maybe that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are not global in the UNIX process model. Each process is provided a set of environment variables by the parent process that starts it. That is typically a **copy** of the parent's environment variables. If you are not starting pycharm from the shell that ran the `export` command pycharm won't see that shell's environment variables.

The behavior you describe means you are not starting pycharm from the shell that did the `export CORENLP_HOME=/path/to/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05`.

P.S., The UNIX process model also means that a process cannot modify the environment variables of a different process.