# setting environment variable in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables

I am trying to learn flask and for the same created a small program. When I try to run it I am getting the below error. `flask run` Error-

```
* Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

if I try to change the file name to `app.py` it runs smooth but when the file name is `flaskblog.py` it isn't working.

I tried setting up the environment variables as suggested in the blog-> [How to set environment variables in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm) but nothing worked.

Screenshots attached.
[content of environment variable file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVjLs.png)

[image: shows envfile option is checked under flaskblog configuration]

[image: environment variable at project level]

[image: at python console level]

[image: os.environ['FLASK_APP'] output]

Comment: To add, if I run the code with `print(os.environ['FLASK_APP'])` this gives me correct output but the same doesn't work on the terminal

Answer (score 2):

Open Settings -> Tools -> Terminal and there set up the environment variable FLASK_APP=app.py. Next, perform restart of PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by setting up the environment variable on the terminal itself.
`set FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py`

and then it ran like smoothly.