# AWS Wrangler error with establishing engine connection in Python, must specify a region?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

This is probably an easy fix, but I cannot get this code to run. I have been using AWS Secrets Manager with no issues on Pycharm 2020.2.3. The problems with AWS Wrangler however are listed below:

### Read in Dataframe

```
test_df = pd.read_csv(source, encoding='latin-1')
```

### Check df data types

```
data_types_df = test_df.dtypes
print('Data type of each column of Dataframe:')
print(data_types_df)
```

### Convert columns to correct data types

```
test_df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['C'])

test_df['E'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['E'])
```

### Check df data types

```
df_new = test_df.dtypes
print('Data type of each column of Dataframe:')
print(df_new)
```

## I have tried both snippets below and I get the same error:

```
engine = wr.catalog.get_engine("aws-data-wrangler-redshift", region_name=region_name)

engine = wr.catalog.get_engine('redshift+psycopg2://' + Username + ":" + Password + ClusterURL)
```

## Error:

```
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

Then I was going to try to convert a Pandas Dataframe to a custom table in redshift using one of the two methods below:

```
path = f"s3://{bucket}/stage/"
iam_role = 'ARN'
```

### Copy df to redshift custom table

```
wr.db.copy_to_redshift(
    df=df_new,
    path=path,
    con=engine,
    schema="custom",
    table="test_df",
    mode="overwrite",
    iam_role=iam_role,
    primary_keys=["c"]
)
```

### Pandas df to redshift

```
wr.pandas.to_redshift(
    dataframe=df_new,
    path=path,
    schema="custom",
    table="test_df",
    connection=con,
    iam_role="YOUR_ROLE_ARN",
    mode="overwrite",
    preserve_index=False
)
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Wrangler uses Boto3 under the hood. And Boto3 will look for the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` env variable. So you have two options:

Set this in your `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[default]  
region=us-east-1
```

Or set this as env variable in your PC:

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
```

More specific you can [set environment variables in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm)