# Running remote Pycharm interpreter with tensorflow and cuda (with module load)

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, remote-debugging, environment-modules

I am using a remote computer in order to run my program on its GPU. My program contains some code with tensorflow functions, and for easier debugging with Pycharm I would like to connect via ssh with remote interpreter to the computer with the GPU. This part can be done easily since Pycharm has this option so I can connect there. However, tensorflow is not loaded automatically so I get import error.
Note that in our institution, we run *module load cuda/10.0* and *module load tensorflow/1.14.0* each time the computer is loaded. Now this part is the tricky one. Opening a remote terminal creates another session which is not related to the remote interpreter session so it's not affecting remote interpreter modules.

I know that *module load* in general configures env, however I am not sure how can I export the environment variables to Pycharm's environment variables that are configured before a run.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround after all was relatively simple: first, I have installed the EnvFile plugin, as it was explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708476/13236698

Them I created an .env file with a quick script on python, extracting all environment variables and their values from `os.environ` and wrote them to a file in the following format: `<env_variable>=<variable_value>`, and saved the file with .env extension. Then I loaded it to PyCharm, and voila - all tensorflow modules were loaded fine.