# Set environment variable in PyCharm to None value

Tags: python, pycharm

During debug sessions in `PyCharm` I need to set some environment variables to `None` value.

There is good explanation on how to set Run/Debug configuration environment variables in `PyCharm` [How to set environment variables in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm), but they set each variable to specific value.

It is possible to delete environment variable from Run/Debug configuration setting it to `None`, but I would prefer to keep the variable's name inside `PyCharm` configuration settings for further use.

So how I set it to python `None`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Environment variables behave as Windows determines, and Windows doesn't provide an equivalent of Python's `None`. If you do `SET MYVAR=` at a console prompt, Windows will delete the variable. There is little that PyCharm can do to change that.

But there is nothing to stop you having an environment variable called `#MYVAR` that is set to the old value of `MYVAR`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just have to create different run/debug configurations with different environment variables.